example sentences of the verbs, "deter, enrich, and help", which have content clauses as their subject
I am interested in the question of what kind of verbs allows a content clause as a subject. I found a list of such verbs in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (P.957).

amuse bother deter disgust enrich help
illustrate indicate influence infuriate matter mean
offend reflect reveal show suggest surprise

I also found example sentences of some of the verbs.

That the invading troops have been withdrawn has not affected our government's trade sanctions (from A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language)

is one of them.
But, I haven't been able to find example sentences of deter, enrich, or help.
Could someone give example sentences of these three verbs?

Can't you think of any examples yourself?

@lph Effort is singular; so enriches, not enrich.

I believe the following three sentences fit the pattern and that an indefinite number of sentences can be constructed using similar ideas. // That mean dogs would be in the yard detered them from visiting. That the effort a nation spends on education  enriches it is well known. That taking it one step at a time does help suddenly became obvious to them. –

NB the section states "It should be borne in mind, however, that what licenses a subject of this kind is often not the verb alone, but the verb in combination with one or more complements – for example, such expressions as "bring home to NP that...," "cloud the fact (that)"..., "leave NP Adj P (e.g.leave us confused)", make sense, offer testimony to...,underline the point (that)..."

@LPH Thank you for your help. In your second example, the subject of “enrich” is the effort, a NP. In your  third example, the subject of “help” is “taking it one step at a time”, not a content clause.

That the troops have been withdrawn has not deterred, enriched or helped our sanctions?
